DJI Tello UDP Video Stream Processing using gst-launch
Context:
I've recently undertaken a project to get the DJI Tello Video stream working along with the inflight controls using the package here: https://github.com/Alexander89/rust-tello/tree/master
I've made some minor changes to the package, the most relevant being that I'm forwarding all the packets that I'm receiving on the video port (11111) to port 5000 on localhost.
And then I'm using this command to process the video and display it:
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, width=(int)960, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)24/1, skip-first-bytes=2" ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
But here is the behavior that I notice when I do this:
It looks like only the top of the frame is rendered or maybe a part of the frame is rendered at the top and the rest of it is just green or really pixelated (-_- represents like a part of the frame and the === is the green). And the rendered part of the frame also changes in quality from time to, sometimes its very clear and other times its quite block (you can refer to the image).
A single frame from the stream

-_-_-_-_-_-
==========

I've looked at other posts dealing with some similar issues (Gstreamer UDP stream from Tello drone into RTP) and that is how I was able to get this far, overall I'm curious if anyone can point me in the right direction as to what needs to change.
Let me know if I can provide any additional context, thank you!
So I've tried what I believe to be an equivalent command using ffmpeg: ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:5000 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4 and I've found the output.mp4 to be almost the same as what we saw with the gst-launch command except the non-processed part of the image is just the last row of pixels from the processed part of the image repeated.
I've also tried another command that uses gst-launch: `gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, width=(int)960, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)24/1, skip-first-bytes=2" ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay  config-interval=1 ` but this ended up errorring out.

you are probably missing h264parse element from the first pipeline. h264parse makes sure the stream is in consistent format that is requited by the downstream elements and also it extracts the properties like width,height from the incoming stream which are used by the decoder to decode the stream properly. It looks like the decoder doesn't have this information with your example and hence it produces corrupted/green frames.
So the pipeline should be something like
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, width=(int)960, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)24/1, skip-first-bytes=2" ! h264parse ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false

And the last pipeline that you tried, after adding the payload with rtph264pay, the stream is going nowhere, you need to pass it on to the udpsink to create the UDP stream
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, width=(int)960, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)24/1, skip-first-bytes=2" ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay  config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=x.x.x.x port=5004

And then access the stream on host machine with
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" port=5004 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin. ! queue ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=0 drop-on-latency=false latency=200 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink


Thanks for the suggestion @Akkshay, unfortunately even with the h264parse I see that the behavior is the same.
I've been having a suspicion lately that the reason for this behavior could be caused by the fact that the actual frames themselves are broken and transmitted separately.
I've looked at this repo: https://github.com/m6c7l/dji-ryze-tello/blob/master/examples/video/README.md and I see that the prefix codes are present for only some of the packets.
Do you think that this is a possibility? If so, is there a way for gst to handle this? Or would I need to re-assemble them?
